# custom textfield is added back of table cell only in iOS 7

Tags: uitableview, ios7

In below code cellTextField is adding back to Mastercell this happens only in iOS7, if its going back of cell means i am unable to enter username and password.But its working ion iOS6.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MasterCell *cell;

    // country
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableGLCCellWithIdentifier:[[self class] cellIdentifierTextField] forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"USERNAME", @"Username");


        ((CellTextField *)cell).textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
        ((CellTextField *)cell).textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
        ((CellTextField *)cell).didEndEditingBlock = [self cellTextFieldDidEndEditingBlockWithIndexPath:indexPath];
        //UITextField *sText = [UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180, 0, 80, 44);


    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableGLCCellWithIdentifier:[[self class] cellIdentifierTextField] forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"PASSWORD", @"Password");
        ((CellTextField *)cell).textField.secureTextEntry = YES;



        ((CellTextField *)cell).didEndEditingBlock = [self cellTextFieldDidEndEditingBlockWithIndexPath:indexPath];
    }


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: please add screenshot or description. your question is still not clear.

Comment: In custom cellTextField i am adding textfield to content view. [self.contentView bringSubviewToFront:_textField];
    
    [self.contentView addSubview:_textField];